# Why can't I choose all of my known Python Environments from Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, environment

From Visual Studio Code, I can only see the available environments:

```
Python 2.7
Conda x.x
```

I have the following self-installed Python versions:

```
C:\Python\Python2.7\
C:\Python\Python3.7\
```

Why is Python3.7 not appearing?

Answer (score 0):

- Verify that all binaries are on the same admin elevation level
- - `C:\Python\Python2.7\`  <--- rarely used, NOT elevated as admin
- - `C:\Python\Python3.7\`  <--- frequently used, elevated as admin

`VSCode` itself was NOT elevated, and therefore only allowed non-elevated binaries to be selected.

After elevating the VSCode binary to admin, all Python environments were available.

Comment: what do you mean by admin level? Doesn't this depend on where you have the Python binary, like Windows seems pretty picky about who to let into stuff on the C: drive... (got my Python stuff on the D: drive - no issues selecting any interpreter, with VS code running with user permissions).

Comment: @MrFuppes "Run as Administrator."  the only other admin level windows really offers.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation on environments](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) explains how the extension finds installations of Python as well has how to specify the location manually.

Comment: No where in that documentation does it describe that permission levels influence the selectable environments.  That is why this question has been written and answered as such.